# Unable to access ilo using .Net or Java irc.exe.manifest did not succeed

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, ilo

iLO 3 - 1.80

When using the Remote Console, neither .NET nor Java using either IE or Firefox is working.  When using .NET from IE or Firefox, I receive this error:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.3221.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    clr.dll             : 4.7.3260.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    dfdll.dll           : 4.7.3221.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/jdoe/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary%20Internet%20Files/Content.IE5/K59HMCW5/IRC%20(1).application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : IRC.application, Version=1.2.3.1591, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ccbf8ed862428044, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\K59HMCW5\IRC (1).application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Users/jdoe/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/K59HMCW5/IRC.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\K59HMCW5\IRC.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\K59HMCW5\IRC.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\K59HMCW5\IRC.exe.manifest'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [12/17/2018 2:10:17 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\K59HMCW5\IRC (1).application has started.
    * [12/17/2018 2:10:17 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [12/17/2018 2:10:17 PM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [12/17/2018 2:10:17 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file:///C:/Users/jdoe/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/K59HMCW5/IRC.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\K59HMCW5\IRC.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\K59HMCW5\IRC.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\K59HMCW5\IRC.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Windows 7, TLS 1.2 enabled in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the standalone app (hplocons).  It fixes most of those types of issues

- [HPE Lights-Out Standalone Remote Console for Windows](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_bc8e3ffa59904ec3b505d9964d) - The current edition as of the time of this post
- [Search of "HPLOCONS"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hplocons+site%3Asupport.hpe.com&ia=web) - A web search for future readers in case the URL migrates.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  There were times when I got the remote console working but it was so unresponsive that characters would be duplicated and you couldn't login.  Probably because I have to use RDP in a different geography among other things.  Remember seeing a coworker using this a couple years ago and forgot about it.